# SSH into shell, get 'Error: Can't open display: (null)'

Tags: xorg, ssh, remote-access

I don't want to open an X11 Session or what not, just to open up a shell to a PC.
I type in Terminal:

```
ssh -p 1337 localhost
```

After entering my password, I get the banner, last login, and then the error:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

*Also*, if I type in  a command after localhost, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that you have something in either .profile or .bashrc that requires X. Try logging in with

```
ssh -t server '/bin/bash --noprofile --norc'
```

The `-t` option forces a pseudoterminal ("interactive mode") and the `--noprofile --norc` options to bash prevents reading `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Comment: Works, but I actually want to login to my ZSH :)

Comment: Then run `/usr/bin/zsh -f` :-)